# configure: error: CGAL library not found

Tags: configure, conda, cgal, graph-tool

**My ultimate goal** is to get python package `graph_tool` working on my system and also on ipynb if possible. I have already `brew install graph-tool`, [as indicated here](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#macos-x), but that's still insufficient.

So I follow [Anaconda instructions here](https://gist.github.com/dlozeve/ed59bba8bc8cb9b21e2af36cc9766938), and I make decent progress, until the `CGAL` Library could not be found.

Note: to comply with the Anaconda instructions, I installed `anaconda3` and created a new conda environment (named `py36env`) to conda install all the required packages (packages that must also match with python 3.6)

The [entire ./configure output](http://txt.do/dlsnm). Below is a snippet:

```
(py36env) $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env/ --with-python-module-path=/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env/lib/python3.6/site-packages --with-cgal=/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env/
.
.
checking whether CGAL is available in /Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env/... no
configure: error: CGAL library not found.
```

The [entire config.log](https://file.io/gKMXQM). Below is a snippet:

```
configure:21200: checking whether CGAL is available in /Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env/
configure:21236: g++ -std=gnu++14 -o conftest -fopenmp -O3 -fvisibility=default -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-deprecated -Wall -Wextra -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0  -DNDEBUG  -I/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env//include -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -L/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env//lib -lCGAL -lCGAL_Core -lgmp -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread conftest.cpp -lgmp -lgmp  >&5
|       #include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
|       #include <CGAL/convex_hull_2.h>
|       typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
|       CGAL::convex_hull_2(points.begin(),points.end(),std::back_inserter(result));
configure:21278: error: CGAL library not found.
CGAL_CPPFLAGS='-I/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env//include'
CGAL_FLAGS=''
CGAL_LDFLAGS='-L/Users/tamtran/anaconda3/envs/py36env//lib -lCGAL -lCGAL_Core -lgmp -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread'
```

Note: Even without the `--with-cgal` tag, the same issue occurs. It's also important (I think) that the CGAL search directory is within `py36env` because CGAL matching with python3.6 is in there, whereas CGAL-python3.5 is in conda root environment. The only differences of `./configure` output without the CGAL directory are:

```
checking whether CGAL is available in /usr... no
checking whether CGAL is available in /usr/local... no
checking whether CGAL is available in /opt... no
checking whether CGAL is available in /opt/local... no
```

Comment: Why is using homebrew insufficient? Also, please post the entire contents of the `config.log` file and the entire output of the `configure` script, if you want to give us any chance of understanding why the build is failing.

Comment: Hi @TiagoPeixoto, when `python3` and `from graph_tool.all import *`, error occurs `Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type`. I will also be attempting to pick that up again. But in the meantime, the Anaconda installation has been boggling me. I've updated the post with links to the entire log and output script!

Comment: Did you get this working?  I'm curious which `conda install cgal` worked

Answer (score 0):

on mac os x You must use -lcgal (is using brew)

for example on fedora linux -lCGAL

Comment: Can you give an example of the -lcgal flag? Where do we use it. I tried in both brew install and in the ./configure