# Crash with BoostPolygonSet since gcc update to 4.9.0

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-geometry

My Linux distribution recently updated from gcc 4.8.x to 4.9.0. Since then i am experiencing a crash when working with boost polygon set, even with simplest usage from the examples:

```
using namespace boost::polygon;
using namespace boost::polygon::operators;

geometry::BoostPolygonSet ps;
ps += rectangle_data<int>(0,0,10,10);
```

Crashes on the ps += line with the last thing being in:

```
/usr/include/boost/polygon/detail/polygon_arbitrary_formation.hpp
```

Line 289, which says:

```
Unit localx = *x_;
```

And *x_ is null

I tried different workarounds but nothing helps. Unfortunately ArchLinux does not provide a way to have more than 1 gcc versions installed in parallel, so i need to get it to work.

Any ideas? Thanx!

**Update:**

Recent archlinux update to gcc package gcc 4.9.0-2 solved the problem. Either a bug in gcc, or, due to the numbering, more possible a bug in ArchLinux package system. Not sure how to close a question (and yes i searched help ;-) ) consider it solved.

Comment: are you sure you've done a full rebuild of all linked objects?

Comment: Well, i pretty much was, but just to ensure that its not some b0rken build dependencies i just removed all build directories from the project and built from scratch: Crash still remains.

Comment: And the boost library dependencies (if there are any for Boost Geometry)

Comment: I don't use self built boost, it's the system installation from ArchLinux... do they really need to recompile all libraries? That would be weired and they sure have not done so far.

Comment: Yes, you need to recompile all libraries if you switch major versions of GCC, because of ABI breaking changes. Anything else -> undefined behaviour

Comment: No, you certainly don't. GCC is ABI-compatible with itself going back many, many major versions. libstdc++ for 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 are ABI-incompatible with the others for *reasons* but all other versions are completely compatible. It's probably a bug in Boost, I feel, that the GCC update simply exposed.

Comment: Do you mean `*x_` is null, or `x_` is null? If the latter, obviously that's a bug in the code, not the compiler.

Comment: Not sure what i mean ;) - QtCreator says: Name: this->x_, Value: 0x0, Type: *int - I assumed that means null pointer.

Comment: ABI compatibility  - "Since gcc-3.4.0, the ABI is forward compatible. I.E. a library made using an older release can be linked with a newer one and it should work (the reverse doesn't)."(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801938/gcc-abi-compatibility)

Comment: This is Boost.Polygon, NOT Boost.Geometry.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with gcc 4.9.0 (on gentoo).  Since ArchLinux updated to a more recent snapshot of gcc, this will hopefully be solved in gcc 4.9.1 I guess!

Comment: The question doesn't need closing. It needs an answer, and you can now provide that i think:). After that you can approve the answer and you're done:)