# How should I handle ABI incompatibility between gcc-4.9 and gcc-5?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, abi

I have recently upgraded my dev machine to Ubuntu 16.04

The default version of gcc is `gcc-5.3.1`.

A problem that I have is a vendor supplied library is only built using gcc-4.9, which is not compatible with gcc-5.

I have asked the vendor to provide a new version of the library, but it is unlikely that that will happen any time soon.

In the meantime I have installed `gcc-4.9.3` from Ubuntu's package repos.

I now have both gcc-4.9 and gcc-5 installed:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/gcc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 May  9 11:49 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 838008 Apr 13 23:23 /usr/bin/gcc-4.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 915704 Apr 13 11:29 /usr/bin/gcc-5
```

I tried to build our source with gcc-4.9, but now I come up against the same ABI issues, but going the other way.

The problem I have is that we have a bunch of dependencies which we would typically install from the distro packages

```
sudo apt-get install \
    python-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libboost-all-dev \
    libprotobuf-dev \
    libgoogle-perftools-dev \
    postgresql \
    libpqxx-dev
```

Whilst I can configure my build to use gcc-4.9

```
mkdir build && cd build
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9 cmake ..
make -j8
```

I now get linker errors when linking against `libtcmalloc_minimal.a`, `libprotobuf.a` etc.

So the next step that I tried was to remove all the dependencies installed from the distro repos and start building the dependencies from source.

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9 ./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
```

The problem here is that I'm starting to head down a rabbit-hole. Each dependency has other dependencies, and I'm not sure where it's going to end.

The other option is to downgrade back to Ubuntu 14.04 or some version which ships with gcc-4.9 instead of gcc-5.

Before I try this thurmonuclear option, I was wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Maybe it's possible to install from repos built with gcc-4.9, or some other way?

Comment: Its been while since I used GCC, but if the library is already compiled, what does it matter if your using a different version of GCC to compile your own code that references the library?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a static library, and needs to be linked into my binary. gcc-5 and gcc-4.9 have incompatible ABIs

Comment: You don't need GCC 4.9, [you can use GCC 5 with the old ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx). But this won't help you with the many distro-provided libraries that use the new ABI, especially if your vendor-supplied library is linked to them. If the vendor-supplied library *isn't* linked to other C++ libraries, it may be possible to split your code in bits compiled with the old ABI and bits compiled with the new ABI, with an ABI-neutral layer to handle communication. Can you give more info about what your vendor's library is linked to?

Comment: @hvd I don't have that info unfortunately. I'm starting to lean towards setting up a chroot jail

Comment: "gcc-5 and gcc-4.9 have incompatible ABIs". It is not very clear which specific ABI changes you are talking about, and what exact error messages you are getting.

Comment: @n.m. [*The C++ runtime library (libstdc++) uses a new ABI by default*](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#libstdcxx). The errors I'm getting are linker errors when trying to link against the vendor supplied library. Undefined references IIRC - although I've since nuked everything, so it'll be a while before I can rebuild and confirm

Comment: So you have a vendor-supplied C++ library that conforms to the old ABI and a distro that is built to the new ABI, am I right? You can create a chroot jail/virtual machine/dedicated compilation server/whatever and populate it with the old ABI libraries, or pressure your vendor to supply a new ABI or [dual ABI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36205151/775806) (disclaimer:shameless-plug) library. If you cannot do the latter, try the virtual machine option.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, that is where I ended up (chroot/vm or get new library from vendor).

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you provided more details regarding ABI problems you get (linker errors, runtime crashes, etc.). Are you problems caused by `std::string` and `std::list` being used in vendor's library public interface?