# boost.python string compatibility for gcc 5.2.0

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

The function, which takes `std::string` input cannot be correctly exposed via boost.python with gcc/5.2.0; while gcc 4.8.3 works fine. 
p.s. I am using a pre-built libboost_python.so.1.63.

C++ code

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::python;

void func(const std::string & hi)
{
    std::cout<<hi<<std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  def("func", &func);
}
```

Python execution

```
>>> from example import *
>>> func("hi")
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    example.func(str)
did not match C++ signature:
    func(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >)
```

Comment: I think this is the proper duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417707/glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-gcc-4-8-and-abi-compatibility

Comment: Thanks. Both `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0` works. Is there a side effect to do that?

Comment: Yes, means that you are using the old ABI version of libstdc++. But that's what distributions like RH6 are using, so you need the flag to get compatibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_GLIBCXX\_USE\_CXX11\_ABI, GCC 4.8 and ABI compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417707/glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-gcc-4-8-and-abi-compatibility)