# Symbol not found by linker but correct file present

Tags: c++, cmake, ld, conda-build

I'm building something with conda-build and cmake. cmake is being invoked with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$PREFIX -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O3 -fstack-protector -pthread -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --std=gnu++17 -L$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/ -lpolyphemus"
```

This is giving me the following error during linking:

> polarwriter.cpp:(.text+0xe2e): undefined reference to `Polyphemus::Log::Stream()'

`$CONDA_PREFIX/lib` contains libpolyphemus.a, and checking that with `nm` shows:

> 0000000000000860 T Polyphemus::Log::Stream[abi:cxx11]()

...which says to me that the reference it's complaining about is set in a file that's in its linker path and that it's been told to link, unless the `abi:cxx11` bit is doing something to invalidate it.

So I have no idea what else to tell it to do, since it's complaining about a file that it should be able to find. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` tell the linker to *not* use the cxx11abi?

Comment: It looks to me the libs were built with CXX11 ABI so you can't link against it w/o enabled it .. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417707/glibcxx-use-cxx11-abi-gcc-4-8-and-abi-compatibility

Comment: You mix libraries (object files) compiled with different ABI settings.

Comment: Yup, the ABI was the problem. That'll teach me to run with inherited files without paying attention to what they're actually doing. Thanks both, @wcochrane you were first, if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.