# Linking a program to libraries the use different _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI each

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, abi

I am trying to compile a program (using GCC 5.4.O) that depends on two libraries. Library A was compiled using the old ABI, while library B was compiled using the new C++11 ABI (see [Dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)).

If compile the program setting _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 1, I have linking errors with library A. If I set it to 0, I have linking errors with library B.

Would it be possible to instruct the compiler to compile the calls to one library using one value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI and the calls to the other library using another value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI?

If I understood correctly, [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159238/linking-problems-due-to-symbols-with-abicxx11) when compiling a new library that depends on two others but I don't know if the same is true for a program.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be possible to instruct the compiler to compile the calls to one library using one value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI and the calls to the other library using another value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI?

There is no way to tell the compiler to do that for you. It wouldn't work anyway, the old and new `std::string` types are incompatible, that's the whole point of having two different ABIs.

What you can do is manually make sure that all calls to library A happen from code which is compiled with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and all calls to library B happen from code which is compiled with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1`. This implies that you can never make calls to both libraries from a single source file.

You would have to segregate all uses of library A and all uses of library B, and not pass `std::string` (or `std::list`) objects between those two parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to instruct the compiler to compile the calls to one library using one value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI and the calls to the other library using another value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI?

There aren't methods to solve this problem. But, you can re-compile the library A and B on current system using the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` value.

The details can refer [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html).