# GCC undefined references with abi:cxx11

Tags: c++, cmake, abi

I'm compiling C++ programs with gcc `version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)`. Everything is fine at compile time.

I then link those programs with a library that was built with `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)`.

I then get undefined reference link errors:

```
CMakeFiles/FOSSSim.dir/RigidBodies/RigidBodyGRVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV46RigidBodyGRVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver[_ZTV46RigidBodyGRVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver]+0x18): undefined reference to `RigidBodyGRVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/FOSSSim.dir/RigidBodies/RigidBodyGRLCPCollisionResolver.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV31RigidBodyGRLCPCollisionResolver[_ZTV31RigidBodyGRLCPCollisionResolver]+0x18): undefined reference to `RigidBodyGRLCPCollisionResolver::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/FOSSSim.dir/RigidBodies/RigidBodyVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV44RigidBodyVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver[_ZTV44RigidBodyVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver]+0x18): undefined reference to `RigidBodyVelocityProjectionCollisionResolver::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/FOSSSim.dir/RigidBodies/RigidBodyLCPCollisionResolver.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV29RigidBodyLCPCollisionResolver[_ZTV29RigidBodyLCPCollisionResolver]+0x18): undefined reference to `RigidBodyLCPCollisionResolver::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles/FOSSSim.dir/RigidBodies/RigidBodyAllPairsCollisionDetector.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV34RigidBodyAllPairsCollisionDetector[_ZTV34RigidBodyAllPairsCollisionDetector]+0x18): undefined reference to `RigidBodyAllPairsCollisionDetector::getName[abi:cxx11]() const'
```

With some googling, I found some links like [linking-problems-due-to-symbols-with-abicxx11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159238/linking-problems-due-to-symbols-with-abicxx11) dealing with the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` compiling option. Unfortunately, when I use that option, I get a Cmake warning:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
```

**Any clue on the way to solve the issue? Knowing that I would prefer avoiding to change compiler version.**

Thanks.

Comment: Just do not link programs and libraries built with different compiler versions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` is a preprocessor macro that controls the behavior of the GNU C++ standard library implementation.  It needs to be passed to the preprocessor, not CMake.

Use `add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)` in your CMakeLists.txt or pass it via CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS on the command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0' path/to/your/project
```

Note that while this may get your program to build, it likely won't be enough to make everything work.  Mixing object code compiled by different versions of GCC is fraught with issues.