# Using a class and a function from different header files C++ and CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I am learning Modern C++ form a course by University of Bonn.
I have declared a class in a `grass.h` file and its implementation in a corresponding `grass.cpp` file. Similarly in another `tools.h`-`tools.cpp` declaration-implementation pair is a function that takes in a reference to the class object defined above. And finally a `main.cpp` file initialises a Grass object from first pair and passes it to the function from the second pair. I am able to compile `main.cpp` and get the desired output from these command line instructions:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -g -c grass.cpp -o grass.o
c++ -std=c++11 -g -c tools.cpp -o tools.o
c++ -std=c++11 -g main.cpp grass.o tools.o -o main
```

but unable to do so with CMake. I do not know what the command line instructions are called (linking and compiling?).

Here is the code example "grass.h":

```
#include <string>
#pragma once

class Grass
{
private:
    int green_;
    std::string name_;
public:
    Grass(int green, std::string name): green_{green}, name_{name} {}

    int get_green() const;                        // getter functions for 
    const std::string& get_green_name() const;    // both private members
};
```

The functions just return the values and are implemented in "grass.cpp".

Then I have a "tools.h":

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grass.h"

#pragma once

void PrintGrass(Grass& grObj);
```

And this function just prints values from the getter functions of Grass.

Finally, the main.cpp contains:

```
int main ()
{
    Grass grObj{10, "ABC"};
    PrintGrass(grObj);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The CMake error occurs at 100%  Linking CXX executable main. The error is in tools.cpp:
`` undefined reference to `Grass::get_green_name[abi:cxx11]()' `` and
`` undefined reference to `Grass::get_green()' ``.
This means that the the program is unable to find to find the definition of these function, right? The CMake file looks like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0")
add_library(grass grass.cpp)
add_library(tools tools.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main grass tools)
```

How do I make this work with CMake? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It is not a CMake error. Its a linker error complaining of an undefined reference. It means you have declared `get_green()` and `get_green_name()` inside grass.h but you have not implemented them in your grass.cpp file.

Comment: I don't know much cmake, but I guess `target_link_libraries` is just as fragile as regular `-l` flag in gcc and it will discard libraries that are not used at the time. Try `target_link_libraries(main tools grass)` instead.

Comment: Or just don't use libraries, I'm not sure why did you choose this route. `add_executable(main main.cpp grass.cpp tools.cpp)` would work.

Comment: These functions are defined, OP in first paragraph says they are able to link with the first snippet (using gcc directly), but not with CMake. The issue is with CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Your working version doesn't build libraries and link with them. Unless you really intend to build a library for each file, you only need the `set` lines and `add_executable(main main.cpp grass.cpp tools.cpp)`.

Comment: Everything looks OK, I cannot reproduce your problem. Most likely the issue is in your directory structure and the way you invoke CMake, or something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406770/gcc-undefined-references-with-abicxx11). Post the full code (also the implementation in cpp files), your project structure, and the output of `VERBOSE=1 make`

Comment: Thank you for all your ideas. As @Yksisarvinen mentioned, I have implemented those functions in grass.cpp. 
I do not understand how, but @Yksisarvinen 's idea worked.  By writing it as ```target_link_libraries(main tools grass) ``` instead of the original ```target_link_libraries(main grass tools) ``` worked.

Comment: I would love to know why this works. Is it executing them in order they have been written? If so, is it because in the original file ```main``` calls function from ```tools``` in Line 4 first, and then ```tools``` uses an object of ```grass```. And so because it is in that order, it needs them to be written in that order?

Comment: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) Linker is a lazy tool.It goes through libraries one by one and if a library doesn't contain any symbols that are currently missing, it will discard the whole library and forget it existed. Libraries are a fragile thing, and you need to make sure the libraries without dependencies are always last. When calling `gcc` directly, you never used any libraries, so you wouldn't encounter this problem.

Comment: I would like to mention that @Yksisarvinen and @molbdnilo 's ```add_executable(main main.cpp grass.cpp tools.cpp)``` works as well. 
As to why I did the extra steps instead of just this one line, is because I learnt it that way from the guy teaching it. I am new to this and exploring more.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen CMake is able to solve linking ordering problem, when dependencies are known to it. In this example `tools` library depends on `grass` library, but it is not specified anywhere. Proper solution to this problem is to add another line `target_link_libraries(tools grass)`. PS. I suggest to use `target_link_libraries(x PUBLIC y)`, so CMake knows we are using modern syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem solved by adding the include files too into add_library:

> add_library(grass grass.cpp grass.h)

Try this and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I will to summarise the comments section and based on @pptaszni's advice put the entire code and the verbose error here:
**The entire code** in order of dependency:

1. `grass.h` and `grass.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#pragma once

class Grass
{
public:
    Grass(int green, std::string name): green_{green}, name_{name} {}

    int get_green ();
    std::string get_green_name ();
private:
    int green_ = 100;
    std::string name_ = "Joe";
};
```

and

```
#include "grass.h"

Grass::Grass(int green, std::string name): green_{green}, name_{name}{}

int Grass::get_green() {
    return green_;  
}

std::string Grass::get_green_name() { 
    return name_;
}
```

2. `tools.h` and `tools.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grass.h"

#pragma once

void PrintGrass(Grass& grObj);
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grass.h"
#include "tools.h"

void PrintGrass(Grass& grObj)
{
    std::cout << grObj.get_green_name() << ", " << grObj.get_green() << " ";
}
```

3. `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grass.h"
#include "tools.h"
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main ()
{
    Grass grObj{10, "Jane"};
    PrintGrass(grObj);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

4. `CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(Grasses)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0")
add_library(grass grass.cpp)
add_library(tools tools.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main grass tools)
```

The error [output](https://gist.github.com/shrinivas96/156963d3f6312f25fcb8258b04df91ba#file-make_verbose_output-txt) of `make VERBOSE=1` being *verbose*, has been pasted in a Github Gist, so as to not make this post longer than it already is.

**Summary**
What worked? Writing

```
target_link_libraries(main tools grass)
```

instead of

```
target_link_libraries(main grass tools).
```

The take away message from the explanation given by @Yksisarvinen is to always place libraries without any dependencies at the very end. This is because the compiler might take a look at such libraries and discard them, if it does not find any use for it at the moment of processing it.

Another thing that works is just using `add_executable(main main.cpp grass.cpp tools.cpp)` and not adding libraries and then linking them. This was suggested by @molbdnilo and @Yksisarvinen.

Thank you all for helping me in understanding C++ a bit better.

Comment: True issue here is that the `tools` library depends on `grass` library, but it is not specified anywhere. Proper solution to this problem is to add another line `target_link_libraries(tools grass)`