# Should GCC version match between the compiled libraries and executables?

Tags: c++, gcc

I compiled an open source C++ library using an old **GCC 4.8.5**. Now, I am planning to update my C++ executables using **GCC 8.3.1** with **-std=c++17**. Do I still need to recompile also the open source library to match the GCC version used in the executables?

Comment: The library predates GCC 5, and its [C++11 ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159238/linking-problems-due-to-symbols-with-abicxx11). You should recompile.

Comment: Even if you don't have to, is there a reason to not do it? A way more modern compiler version should deliver better results.

Comment: A simple example of binary incompatibility: both versions report a different byte size of objects of type `std::string`: https://godbolt.org/z/YT4xTn.

Comment: @MSalters ohh okay I see. thank you. I will recompile then.

Comment: @mch I was just trying to save a little time recompiling across different servers. I know my reason is a bit lazy and unacceptable. Your point is valid about modern compiler version deliver better results. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLangr Ohh thanks for this. It's time for recompilation then. Thank you