# How to tell if a library is compiled with certain GCC version

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm compiling OpenSSL on Unix-machine. The default compiler is `GCC-4.4.7`. I put an alternative compiler `GCC-5.2.0` in another folder. I usually will prepend the path of alternative compiler to `$PATH` so that `gcc` will always use the one in alternative path.

But now I'm uncertain with the library I compiled, is there a way to tell which gcc is used for compiling my library? A workaround on the `.o` files is appreciated as well.

Comment: Does `readelf -p .comment /path/to/yourprogram` give you the info you want?

Comment: Thank you @MarkPlotnick! This is awesome! exactly what I needed! Could you please convert this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The gcc and clang compiler suites will put a version string in the `.comment` section of an ELF file. (If you generate an intermediate assembly language file, you can see this string as an `.ident` directive).

The GNU linker will merge all the `.comment` sections of its input object files into a single section, eliminating any duplicates.

You can read this section by running `readelf -p .comment /path/to/your/objectfile`. For example, here is an executable made from two relocatable object files, one compiled with gcc and the other with clang:

```
$ readelf -p .comment hello

String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005
  [    2d]  clang version 3.8.1-12ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)
```

Comment: Can we merge relocatable object compiled using different GCC version into a single SO?
If yes, does that imply that the SO can be linked using multiple GCC versions?

Thanks.

Comment: @Wilson I do not have a definitive answer for that, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801938/gcc-abi-compatibility .  I believe that C relocatable objects that have been compiled PIC and whose dependent libraries are either identical or compatible can be linked into a single shared object if the gcc versions are different as long as they're all 4.7.0 or later. (5.1.0 or later if C++ is involved).

Comment: "The GNU loader will merge...": is this not the linker that does that?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger  Quite right. I am old and still call `ld` the loader. Fixed. Thanks.