# Why golang binary that compiled in Debian 9 , cant launch in Centos 7?

Tags: go

Compiled an application on Debian 9, when I try to run on CentosOS, I get

```
./app: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./app)
./app: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./app)
./app: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./app)
```

ldd ./app show

```
bash-4.2$ ldd app 
./app: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./app)
./app: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./app)
./app: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./app)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff24901000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f45a97ff000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f45a94f8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f45a91f5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f45a8fdf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f45a8c12000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f45a9a25000)
```

Comment: Did you compile it with CGO or any other flags/settings separate from plain old `go build`?

Comment: No, just go build -o ./app ./app-folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is likely using [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) implicitly and generating an executable that depends on the [C++ ABI versions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) of the host machine that is doing the compiling (Debian 9). Unfortunately, it appears that your execution target (CentOS 7) has an incompatible ABI.

You can verify by compiling with cgo disabled, e.g.:

```
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o ./app ./app-folder
```

That command will likely fail, so your options are likely to:

1. refactor the parts of your go code which rely on cgo to use native go alternatives, OR...
2. compile on a machine which has a compatible ABI as your execution target platform.

See also [Application binary interface 
(ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [GCC ABI Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801938/gcc-abi-compatibility).