# Referencing std::pow() requires GLIBC2.29

Tags: c++, redhat, cmath

I'm building on Ubuntu 20.04 and my program executed on RedHat 8 just fine until I included `<cmath>` and used `std::pow(double, double)`. Now I get the following error on RedHat 8:

```
/lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /MyOwnLib.so)
```

What is so special about `std::pow` that it requires GLIBC 2.29? This function is very old. Can I somehow force the compiler on Ubuntu to "link" an older version?

Comment: Maybe ship your own libstdc++ with the application? This sometimes breaks things if the system has a newer version of it, so ideally you want a script that plugs it in only if the system version doesn't work.

Comment: Gcc ABI is [forward compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802835/4165552), which means you can do the opposite: compile your program on RedHat8 and run it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special. There's surprising little coordination between gcc, glibc and the linker people, despite them all being "GNU". To tell gcc that `pow` is not new, you can use `asm (".symver pow, pow@GLIBC_2.2.5");`. This will tell gcc that `pow` was available since glibc version 2.2.5, so gcc won't tell the linker that glibc 2.29 is needed. `pow` has been around for way longer of course, but 2.2.5 introduced this versioning scheme.

The downside is that you miss out on the optimized version of `pow` from glibc 2.29, but that it intentional. That optimized version is missing from your RedHat 8 machine.

And just to be complete: this is `pow` from `libm`, which is the math part of `glibc`. It is not `std::pow(double, double)` from C++. That tells us that `std::pow(double, double)` is a thin inline wrapper for `pow`, as expected.

Comment: nm -D libm.so.6 | fgrep "@@GLIBC"  will give you the list of versioned math symbols. Note that the " .6" soname versioning is not used by glibc since they used started using their own versioning mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not ABI stable: when you build something on your machine it will work on your machine only. This is because the binary produced is specific to your architecture.

In this case it seems that there is a mismatch of the C standard library (libc).

If you want to don't depend from the system implementation of the standard C++ you can try to statically link to the standard library.

If you use `gcc` or `clang` try `-static` compiler option.

The solution to your problem would be compile your program to the target platform.

Comment: This first assumption is wrong, very wrong. I've written C++ code that has run on 50 million different machines. The binary produced was "specific" to the Win32 architecture. The real problem is that `glibc` and `stdlibc++` have no SDK against which you can build. Can't specify `-Lglibc=2.29`.

Comment: An easy counter example: try to build using a very recent of C++ on Windows on an older version of Windows where the runtime is not that recent. That won't work! You should distribute also the vc runtime to be safe.

Comment: That's "not to be safe". You should *always* include the VC++ or G++ runtime , because neither is part of Windows. However, because both the VC++ and G++ runtimes are independent from the OS, you can link them statically.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: @MSalters answer is even better, switch to that.

A colleague of mine pointed out that I can use std::powf instead which is available in GLIBC 2.28 and does not require GLIBC 2.29. Not really a solution, but my solution, so I will mark it as accepted answer.

For somebody who can't do that look at the comment of @pptaszni to my original question: probably use an older Linux to compile on.